# NullPointerException while updating data in database

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

The application has 2 Activities, 1st activity has 2 fields and 2nd Activity has 1 feild. The 1st two fields are inserted in the table i.e on 1st activity.As soon as the first two fields are inserted the user is redirected to new activity.The new activity has the 3rd fields which is when saved should be updated in the same table.However, After inserting the 1st two values, when Iam updating the 3rd value in the same table Iam getting nullpointer exception.Thanks in advance.

This is my 2nd activity where Iam updating the 3rd value

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.data3id);
        updatebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.updatebtnid);


        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mRowId=intent.getStringExtra("KEYROWID");


        updatebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            public void onClick(View v) {
                dba = new DBAdapter(v.getContext());

                String data3=ed3.getText().toString();


                dba.open();


                 String updatequery = "UPDATE "+ DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE+ " SET ";

                updatequery = updatequery + "KEY_DATA3='" +data3 +"'";
                Log.v("updatequery",updatequery);
                updatequery = updatequery + " WHERE _id = '" + mRowId + "';";
                Log.v("updatequery-new",updatequery);
                Log.v("test-1","update");
                try{
                    Log.v("test-2","update");
                    myDB.execSQL(updatequery);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Log.v("test-3","update");

                    if(myDB != null)myDB.close();

                }


            }
```

This is my DBAdapter class

```
public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID= "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DATA1="data1";
    public static final String KEY_DATA2="data2";
    public static final String KEY_DATA3="data3";


    private static String TAG="DBAdapter";

    static String DATABASE_NAME="update.db";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE="update_table";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION=2;


    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
      "create table update_table(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "data1 varchar, data2 varchar, data3 varchar);";




    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }


        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS update_table");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }




    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }


    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }





    public long createddb(String data1,String data2,String data3) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();


        initialValues.put(KEY_DATA1, data1);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATA2, data2);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATA3, data3);


       return  mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);




    }



    public boolean deleteSaleseditdetails(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }




    public int fetchmaxId(){
        //return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID},null, null, null, null, null);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT max("+KEY_ROWID+") from " + DATABASE_TABLE ;
         Cursor c= mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getInt(0);
        //  cursor.moveToLast();


    }



    public boolean deletedb(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

Following is the error which Iam getting into logcat file

```
02-02 18:10:48.751: W/System.err(17003): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at com.example.testupdate.Activity2$1.onClick(Activity2.java:62)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-02 18:10:48.761: W/System.err(17003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which one of those is 62 line in your `Activity2`?

Comment: Perhaps this post may be answer to your question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678351/android-sqlite-null-pointer-exception

Comment: @Mosquito : line number 62 is myDB.execSQL(updatequery); in Activity2

Comment: ok, now find out which one of them is null and why

Comment: initially while inserting the feids into database i have inserted 3rd feild as null in 1st activity.And as soon as the 2nd activity is called the 3rd values is retrieved and updated in the same table

Comment: ok..after making few changes i.e myDB=DBAdapter.openDatabase(getApplicationContext(), DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME);  . Iam getting an error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_DATA3: UPDATE update_table SET KEY_DATA3='dwt' WHERE _id = '22';

Comment: @Shweta It's because you DON'T have a column named "KEY_DATA3". Instead you should write "data3" from what I see in your `DATABASE_CREATE` `String`.

Comment: you DON'T have a column named "KEY_DATA3" , KEY_DATA3 is a string variable , it is not the column . IF you are still learning , learn SQL concept first , if you come to know SQl then there should not be problem. Fetch the DB from device/emulator check the columns of table in it. Then do the query

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in `myDB` field which is `null`. I can't see that in your code, but check if you have your `myDB` field initialized somewhere. If not, that is causing your `NullPointerException`.

By the way, you're checking if `myDB` is not `null` in order to know if you should close it:

```
if(myDB != null)myDB.close();
```

But you're not doing the same check when call `myDB.execSQL(updatequery);`

Comment: as you can see in the activity, I have intiallized the DBAdapter class as dba = new DBAdapter(v.getContext()); and db.open

Comment: ok..after making few changes i.e myDB=DBAdapter.openDatabase(getApplicationContext(), DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME); . Iam getting an error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_DATA3: UPDATE update_table SET KEY_DATA3='dwt' WHERE _id = '22'

Comment: @Shweta It's because you DON'T have a column named "KEY_DATA3". Instead you should write "data3" from what I see in your `DATABASE_CREATE` `String`.

Comment: thanks for your response.But even after changing the "KEY_DATA3" to data3, i am getting the same error

Comment: you get error stating that there's no column named "KEY_DATA3", or no column named "data3"?

Comment: it gives NullPointerEception"the one which i stated above".Though, I checked putting logcat, the query is getting all the required feild