# Android sqlite update method; java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am working on android app. and trying to save some data in sqlite db. I am updating record if I found id or else i am just inserting record. Insertion works fine but update isn't working. Following is method in which I am doing this save work.

```
public boolean saveSite(View view){
    EditText sitename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.site_name);
    EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
    EditText host = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.host);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    RadioGroup grp =  (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.type);

    int selectedID = grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton type = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedID);

    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

    data.put(DBContract.Site.COLUMN_NAME_SITE_NAME, sitename.getText().toString());
    data.put(DBContract.Site.COLUMN_NAME_LOGIN, login.getText().toString());
    data.put(DBContract.Site.COLUMN_NAME_HOST, host.getText().toString());
    data.put(DBContract.Site.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, password.getText().toString());
    data.put(DBContract.Site.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, type.getText().toString());

    long saved = -1;
    if(editId == null) {
        try {
            saved = db.insertOrThrow(DBContract.Site.TABLE_NAME, null, data);
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Site name already exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        String[] arr = new String[] {String.valueOf(editId)};

        try {
            Log.d("data", data.toString());
            Log.d("ID", DBContract.Site._ID);
            Log.d("table name", DBContract.Site.TABLE_NAME);
            Log.d("arr", arr[0]);
            saved = db.update(DBContract.Site.TABLE_NAME, data, DBContract.Site._ID + " = ?", arr);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            Log.d("Exception", ex.getMessage().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Site name already exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    if( saved != -1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", "Connection Saved Successfully");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I know you will need log to indentify so here it is:

```
    09-12 21:31:47.464  14132-14430/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {cmp=com.example.hafiz.ftp/.SiteManager (has extras)} from pid 19238
09-12 21:31:47.524  14132-14430/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
09-12 21:31:48.134  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:48.144  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:48.204  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:48.554  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/Map﹕ {host=host1, type=Active, site_name=teste, _id=1, password=pass, login_name=login1}
09-12 21:31:48.624  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:48.624  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:48.684  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:49.184  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:49.184  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:49.254  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:49.324  19238-19240/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 141K, 3% free 9329K/9607K, paused 6ms+6ms
09-12 21:31:49.634  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:49.654  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:49.694  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:50.064  14132-14159/system_process W/ProcessStats﹕ Skipping unknown process pid 19340
09-12 21:31:50.094  14132-14159/system_process W/ProcessStats﹕ Skipping unknown process pid 19342
09-12 21:31:50.154  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:50.154  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:50.184  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:50.234  14132-14269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.hafiz.ftp/.SiteManager: +2s629ms
09-12 21:31:55.164  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/data﹕ host=host1 type=Passive site_name=tester password=pass login_name=login1
09-12 21:31:55.164  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/ID﹕ _id
09-12 21:31:55.174  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/table name﹕ site
09-12 21:31:55.174  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/arr﹕ 1
09-12 21:31:55.194  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-12 21:31:55.194  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2ba041f8)
09-12 21:31:55.254  19238-19238/com.example.hafiz.ftp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3045)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3512)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14106)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3040)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3512)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14106)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.hafiz.ftp.SiteManager.saveSite(SiteManager.java:104)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3040)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3512)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14106)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 21:31:55.334  14132-14430/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.hafiz.ftp/.SiteManager
09-12 21:31:55.374  14132-14430/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21015
09-12 21:31:55.904  14132-14152/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2c4b6ba8 com.example.hafiz.ftp/.SiteManager}
09-12 21:31:56.004  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:56.004  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:56.024  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:56.634  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:56.694  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:56.844  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:57.134  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:57.134  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:57.174  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:57.864  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:57.864  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:58.234  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:58.334  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:58.334  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:58.394  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:58.836  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:58.836  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:58.894  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:59.314  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:59.314  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:59.354  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:31:59.854  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:31:59.854  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:31:59.944  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:00.334  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:00.344  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:00.414  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:00.814  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:00.844  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:00.914  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:01.354  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:01.414  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:01.544  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:01.834  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:01.834  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:01.884  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:02.344  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:02.344  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:02.404  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:02.834  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:02.834  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:02.874  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:03.394  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:03.394  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:03.494  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:03.864  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:03.864  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:03.914  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:04.434  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:04.434  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:04.534  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:04.914  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:04.914  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:04.975  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:05.434  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:05.434  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:05.514  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:05.714  14132-14152/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
09-12 21:32:05.904  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19238 SIG: 3
09-12 21:32:05.904  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 21:32:05.944  19238-19243/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 21:32:06.194  14132-14152/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{2c597e50 com.example.hafiz.ftp/.MainActivity}
09-12 21:33:19.615  14132-14388/system_process W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
09-12 21:33:20.234  14132-14134/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1273K, 14% free 11052K/12807K, paused 27ms+38ms
09-12 21:33:38.534  14396-14400/com.android.phone D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 430K, 6% free 9484K/10055K, paused 18ms+16ms
```

So let me know what i am doing wrong. Parameters passed to update method are also in log via `Log.d()` that can be seen right before exception.

### ----- Update -----

In case I don't handle exception in case of `db.update()` call, log can be like below pasting it here because I think it is more descriptive or detailed and can be helpful.

```
    09-12 22:31:02.715  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/data﹕ host=host1 type=Active site_name=teste password=pass login_name=login1
09-12 22:31:02.724  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/ID﹕ _id
09-12 22:31:02.744  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/table name﹕ site
09-12 22:31:02.744  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/arr﹕ 1
09-12 22:31:02.774  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-12 22:31:02.774  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2ba041f8)
09-12 22:31:02.834  15108-15108/com.example.hafiz.ftp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3045)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3512)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14106)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3040)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3512)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14106)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:96)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1761)
            at com.example.hafiz.ftp.SiteManager.saveSite(SiteManager.java:101)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3040)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3512)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14106)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 22:31:02.914  14132-14132/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.hafiz.ftp/.SiteManager
09-12 22:31:02.954  14132-14132/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21015
09-12 22:31:03.454  14132-14139/system_process I/dalvikvm﹕ Jit: resizing JitTable from 2048 to 4096
09-12 22:31:03.664  14132-14152/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2c5dc940 com.example.hafiz.ftp/.SiteManager}
09-12 22:31:03.734  14132-14134/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 340K, 14% free 11085K/12807K, paused 17ms+29ms
09-12 22:31:03.974  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:03.984  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:04.025  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:04.834  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:04.844  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:04.935  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:05.264  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:05.264  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:05.284  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:05.804  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:05.845  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:05.964  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:06.224  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:06.234  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:06.264  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:06.835  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:06.835  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:06.984  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:07.314  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:07.314  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:07.365  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:07.775  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:07.775  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:07.874  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:08.295  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:08.295  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:08.384  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:08.924  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:08.924  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:09.025  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:09.324  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:09.335  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:09.524  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:09.835  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:09.845  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:09.895  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:10.364  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:10.375  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:10.424  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:10.844  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:10.884  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:10.935  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:10.955  14132-14159/system_process W/ProcessStats﹕ Skipping unknown process pid 15472
09-12 22:31:11.004  14132-14159/system_process W/ProcessStats﹕ Skipping unknown process pid 15474
09-12 22:31:11.406  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:11.406  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:11.494  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:11.857  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:11.857  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:11.895  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:12.404  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:12.404  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:12.494  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:12.864  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:12.864  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:12.926  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:13.024  14132-14152/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
09-12 22:31:13.435  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:13.435  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:13.524  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:13.914  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:13.914  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:13.965  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:14.474  14132-14152/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 15108 SIG: 3
09-12 22:31:14.474  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-12 22:31:14.554  15108-15113/com.example.hafiz.ftp I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-12 22:31:14.694  14132-14152/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{2c48cd98 com.example.hafiz.ftp/.MainActivity}
```

See the 'cause' section of log.

Comment: please post your complete code

Comment: Can you tell me which one is line `104` of the `SiteManager` class ?

Comment: @Titus this is the line where db.update() is called.

Comment: @Titus I just noticed that if i don't handle exception then log is more descriptive so pasting that log here as well.

Comment: The problem may be that the database is closed. Here is a similar situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678351/android-sqlite-null-pointer-exception

Comment: @sourabhbans db is th object of `SQLiteDatabase` class that come with android.

Comment: @Titus same db object work in case of insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db` is null on the line `saved = db.update(DBContract.Site.TABLE_NAME, data, DBContract.Site._ID + " = ?", arr);`

Edit:

Are you opening and closing the database?

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7999165/1695687

This person is getting the exact same crash at `SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock`

Comment: I don't think that is the case because the OP said that the insertion works.

Comment: Yes, insertion works, and if you are saying it null because you can't see initialization then it is property set in onCreate() already.

Comment: Are you opening and closing the database?  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7999165/1695687

That guy is getting the exact same crash at `SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock`

Comment: @ieatacid i think you got it right, because i was having one more operation in case of update and closing connection in that operation i think that can be the issue.

Comment: @ieatacid so you were right but it was closed not null because of another db operation for populating form. thanks

Comment: so can't mark answer correct, please modify this in your answer so that i can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @Hafiz Ok, I fixed it up.

Answer (score 0):

may be here is the problem...

```
if( saved != -1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", "Connection Saved Successfully");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

you are calling it from onClick() listener so don't use `this` keyword for Context , i think you should use `YourActivity.this` or something similar.

Comment: this wasn't the problem.